# Dragon Error Code: HOOKERR_NONOTIFYWINDOW with Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, dragon-naturally-speaking

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 with Chrome. From time to time, I have a Error Code: HOOKERR_NONOTIFYWINDOW when trying to write text by speech with Dragon in Google Chrome:

[image]

Chrome Incognito mode, Firefox, Notepad++ have the same issue. Notepad doesn't have the issue. I don't use the Dragon dictation box: I directly (attempt to) dictate in the program. The issue appeared a few days ago. It used to work fine before that for several years on the same computer.

How to fix it? The issue goes away for a while when I reboot the computer, but I would prefer not to have to reboot it.

Comment: I do not know,, except that it seems to be a Windows COM error.   Does  this article shed any light ?    ...... https://www.knowbrainer.com/forums/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=4&threadid=15620

Comment: Closevoter: please tell me what that I should clarify.

Comment: @John thanks, I'll try to use Google incognito next time I encounter the issue to see whether this comes from a plugin.

Comment: Thanks - let us know when the error recurs.

Comment: @John the error reappeared. Chrome Incognito mode, Firefox, Notepad++ have the same issue. Notepad doesn't have the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit: the Error Code `HOOKERR_NONOTIFYWINDOW` appears as soon as I start Adobe Acrobat. Closing it and killing all its processes doesn't solve the issue: I only found rebooting so far to fix the issue. I have no clue how comes the error appeared in the first place because I haven't updated Acrobat for a while for a few months (ironically, because of another Acrobat issue).

Thanks to John for pointing me to https://www.knowbrainer.com/forums/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=4&threadid=15620 ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20220127052055/https://www.knowbrainer.com/forums/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=4&threadid=15620)), which raised my suspicion against Adobe Acrobat.